# Vim: Smart indent when entering insert mode on blank line?

Tags: vim, customization, indentation

When I open a new line (via 'o') my cursor jumps to a correctly indented position on the next line. On the other hand, entering insert mode while my cursor is on a blank line doesn't move my cursor to the correctly indented location.

How do I make vim correctly indent my cursor when entering insert mode (via i) on a blank line?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

`cc` will replace the contents of the current line and enter insert mode at the correct indentation - so on a blank line will do exactly what you're after.

I believe that the behaviour of `i` you describe is correct because there are many use cases where you *want* to insert at that specific location on a blank line, rather than jumping to wherever vim guesses you want to insert.

Comment: Well my solution will make 'i' behave that way only when the line is empty - so just one use case. 'i' will behave normally in all other situations. That being said, cc is built in and more appropriate imo. Accepting

Comment: what I love about vim is no matter how long you use it, you can still learn new stuff every day. I use dd, yy, and c with other modifiers extensively every day, never occured to me to try cc. +1

Comment: For me, this doesn't work *if there's a blank line* between the previous line and the line you want to indent. (i.e. you've hit `o` twice, because you want spacing between the previous line and the next section of code.) I'd still love to see a quick way to jump into insert mode, at the indentation level of the *previous line of actual code*.

Comment: This only started working for me after activating `cindent`, with `smartindent` `cc` didn't work as described.

Comment: I agree with @ELLIOTTCABLE. That's how I found my way here. Regarding sml's comment about "many use cases....". Perhaps, but that's ~2% of the time for me, in which case I can <BS> my way back to the beginning. 98% of the time, I would like to use my present level of indent.

Answer (score 14):

Well this actually wasn't as bad as I thought it would be. One way to enable this is to add the following to your ~/.vimrc

```
"smart indent when entering insert mode with i on empty lines
function! IndentWithI()
    if len(getline('.')) == 0
        return "\"_ccO"
    else
        return "i"
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> i IndentWithI()
```

It simply checks for an empty line when you hit 'i' from insert mode. If you are indeed on an empty line it will delete it and open a new one, effectively leveraging the working 'open line' behavior.

Note: "_ before the cc makes sure that your register doesn't get wiped

Comment: I found that `ccO` didn't work either, but `ddko` did (delete current line, go to previous line, add new line).

Comment: I had to change `"\"_ccO"` to `"\"_cc"`, it was inserting the O and I'm not sure why it was there. Otherwise super helpful function, thanks.

Comment: After using this for a few days, I changed this behavior to work with `a` and not `i`, which makes more logical sense to me since I think of them as being on different sides of the implicit indentation. So `i` inserts at the far left as before, `a` appends after the auto-indentation.

Answer (score 10):

On an empty line, to enter insert mode correctly indented, you can simply use `s`.

Note that `s` is a synonym for `cl`, so if you're *not* actually on an empty line, it'll end up deleting a single character and not indenting.  In that case, you're better off using `cc`, as sml suggested some 18 months ago.  But I've frequently improved my score at VimGolf by using this shortcut, so thought I'd mention it.  ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm still learning things about vim everyday.

Comment: @DaneO'Connor we all are! :)