# How to go back to the "smart-indent" in vim from the start of a line

Tags: vim

When I press `o` or `O` it indents to the necessary level since I have `smartindent` on. However, what happens when I'm at the start of a line and want to go to where the 'smartindent' for that line would be. Is there a way to do that? Here is an example video of what I'm trying to do:

https://gyazo.com/da4351def5a0af93df5f7fff0d462adb

I suppose <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> is the best way I have thought up so far.

Comment: How about `b` `o`? I guess it only works when you're right below the line as in your video, but not for arbitrary lines...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vim: Smart indent when entering insert mode on blank line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003393/vim-smart-indent-when-entering-insert-mode-on-blank-line)

Comment: @ggorlen thanks for that, Yes I think `cc` is better than the `ddO` / `bo` option.

Comment: `cc` or `S` respect an indent.

Comment: @Matt thanks, even better. `S` is the simplest/best. Oddly enough the accepted answer doesn't mention that (another one does though).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the most simple thing you can do is press `S`, it works just like pressing `cc`

Comment: This doesn't work if  your goal is to give a blankline a hanging indent in order to fix the bug that prevents vim folding indented sections that contain within them blanklines without any indent spaces. Press `S` on a blankline and it will indeed cause vim to enter `insert' mode on that line at an autoindent level flush with the line above. But press `Esc` to leave indent mode and thus leave the blankline with its hanging indent, and the indent spaces will disappear again.

Answer (score 3):

In insert mode, <kbd>CTRL-F</kbd> is the default key for re-indenting the current line. See `:h i_ctrl-f` for more information.

Comment: Hm, looks like I learned something new today. It turns out <kbr>CTRL-F</kbr> is only used when `cindent` is turned on. I'm not sure what language you use, but you could check whether it already is on with `:set cindent?`. If it is, just hit <kbr>CTRL-F</kbr> while at the start of the line. If not, you could turn on `cindent` with `:set cindent` and customize it if necessary.

Also, I saw some threads that suggest `smartindent` is outdated and should not be used. I would suggest either just using `autoindent`, finding a filetype plugin depending on what language you use, or using `cindent`.